# Selecting a resource programatically in Eclipse does not expand tree

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I have the following problem with my RCP Eclipse application: I am trying to set selection on an IResource within a Project Explorer tree. 
Code I am using is:

```
final IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
final IViewPart viewPart = page.findView(IPageLayout.ID_PROJECT_EXPLORER);
final ISelectionProvider selProvider = viewPart.getSite().getSelectionProvider();
selProvider.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(mrcReportRuleOccurrence.getIResource()));
```

The code seems to work only if the leaf was already once expanded in the tree. If the tree is completely collapsed, the code does not make eclipse expand the containing folder and select the desired file in the project explorer. Does anyone know how to bring this about?

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking if the selection provider is a `Viewer` and using the `setSelection(selection. reveal)` method:

```
if (selProvider instanceof Viewer) {
  ((Viewer)selProvider).setSelection(selection, true);
}
```

It may also be necessary to use a `TreeSelection` with a `TreePath` for the selection rather than just `StructuredSelection`.

```
TreePath path = new TreePath(.... array of objects ...);

TreeSelection selection = new TreeSelection(path);
```

Where 'array of objects' is the path through the tree to the resource.

But selecting items in the tree of a different view is not what the `ISelectionProvider` interface is for. There is no guarantee that this can be done using this interface.

Comment: The instance check and the setSelection do not seem to make a difference. As for the TreeSelection, I am failing to get a TreeSelection from an IResource...

Comment: You don't get TreeSelection from IResource, you build it using a TreePath. Exactly what the project explorer wants in the path I am not sure. Added a bit more to the answer.

Comment: I have succesfully modified the code to recieve a tree selection but it still displays exactly the same behavior, if the tree was not open, it will not select the element. If the usery manually expands the tree at least once the code will jump to the element even if the tree is collapsed.

Comment: Well you might be able to do something with `expandToLevel`, but this is not what the selection provider interface is for and there is no guarantee that this is possible at all.

Comment: neither the Viewer class nor the selection provider provide the expandToLevel method

Comment: TreeViewer does. The viewer is probably a TreeViewer

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well. The same problem still occurrs.